# Using pyCrypto to hash results in a TypeError

Tags: python, hash, encoding, pycrypto

I'm trying to use pycrypto for python 3.5.1 on win10
using this simple piece of code for has:

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256  
SHA256.new('abc').hexdigest()
```

resulting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "E:/Python/C.py", line 2, in <module>  
    SHA256.new('abc').hexdigest()  
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py", line 88, in new
    return SHA256Hash().new(data)
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py", line 75, in new
    return SHA256Hash(data)
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py", line 72, in __init__
    HashAlgo.__init__(self, hashFactory, data)
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.update(data)
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py", line 69, in update
    return self._hash.update(data)
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: "Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing" is pretty clear.

Comment: Use the .encode() function on your 'abc' string before running the hashing function, e.g. 'abc'.encode('utf-8')

Comment: thank all , worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.encode()` function on your 'abc' string before running the hashing function.

For example, if you wish to use *Unicode* encoding:

```
'abc'.encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

means you should do something like this:

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256

print(SHA256.new('abc'.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
```